# Integrating Custom Database with Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, mysql, customization

I Have a Wordpress Site with few users who are my college students

They Registered using their RollNumbers/HallTicket Numbers as their usernames in Wordpress site

Now I Have Another Database with Their Personal Details like Marks, Rank etc

Now I want to Integrate this Database to Wordpress so that when student/user logins , then he/her could see their respective marks and other details

I Just want your suggestions/ideas to implement this, Not asking for a Complete solution

Thankyou

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are asking. You have WP, custom table, users... Then what?

Comment: @Rarst Question Edited, Could u please suggest me

Comment: use `wp_get_current_user()->ID` to get the id  of the current logged in user & then create an instance of  wpdb class & use it to query the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to query your custom data from MySQL. Depending on your implementation you would either use:

- global `$wpdb` object, if your custom data is in same database as WP itself
- new custom instance of `wpdb` class if you need to connect to different database for custom data

Comment: We can use wpdb custom queries, but where we need to write our custom queries , we need to create a php file for that or we need to write it in an existing file ??

Comment: @Aryan that can be done in different places, typical are theme's `functions.php` or creating a plugin.